# Sudoku Solving - Skip on stage in backtracking

Tags: c, recursion, backtracking

I already asked for help here, but nobody answer, and it really frustrating,
I am trying to write a code that solve a Sudoku in recursive function (backtracking),
here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define SIZE        9
#define SQUARE_SIZE 3

void print(int arrBoard[SIZE][SIZE])
{
     system("cls");
     int i, j;
     for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     {
         if (i % 3 == 0) printf("_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _\n");
         for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
         {
             if (j % 3 == 0) printf("| ");
             printf("%d ", arrBoard[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
     }

     Sleep(100);
}

BOOL IsValidRow(int arrBoard[SIZE][SIZE], int iNum, int iRow)
{
    int iCol;

    for (iCol = 0; iCol < SIZE; iCol++)
        if (arrBoard[iRow][iCol] == iNum) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL IsValidCol(int arrBoard[SIZE][SIZE], int iNum, int iCol)
{
    int iRow;

    for (iRow = 0; iRow < SIZE; iRow++)
        if (arrBoard[iRow][iCol] == iNum) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL IsValidSquare(int arrBoard[SIZE][SIZE], int iNum, int iRow, int iCol)
{
    iRow-= (iRow % SQUARE_SIZE);
    iCol-= (iCol % SQUARE_SIZE);

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SQUARE_SIZE; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < SQUARE_SIZE; j++)
            if (arrBoard[iRow + i][iCol + j] == iNum) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL IsValid(int arrBoard[SIZE][SIZE], int iNum, int iRow, int iCol)
{
    if (IsValidRow(arrBoard, iNum, iRow) == FALSE) return FALSE;
    if (IsValidCol(arrBoard, iNum, iCol) == FALSE) return FALSE;
    if (IsValidSquare(arrBoard, iNum, iCol, iRow) == FALSE) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL _Solve(int arrBoard[SIZE][SIZE], int iRow, int iCol)
{
    if (iRow == 9) return TRUE;

    if (arrBoard[iRow][iCol])
    {
        iRow = (iCol == 8) ? iRow + 1 : iRow;
        iCol = (iCol == 8) ? 0 : iCol + 1;

        if(_Solve(arrBoard, iRow, iCol)) return TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    }

    int iNewNum, iOldRow, iOldCol;
    for (iNewNum = 1; iNewNum <= SIZE; iNewNum++)
    {
        if (IsValid(arrBoard, iNewNum, iRow, iCol))
        {
            arrBoard[iRow][iCol] = iNewNum;
            print(arrBoard);
            iOldRow = iRow; iOldCol = iCol;
            iRow = (iCol == 8) ? iRow + 1 : iRow;
            iCol = (iCol == 8) ? 0 : iCol + 1;

            if (_Solve(arrBoard, iRow, iCol)) return TRUE;

            iRow = iOldRow; iCol = iOldCol;
            arrBoard[iRow][iCol] = 0;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arrBoard[SIZE][SIZE] =
    {0, 1, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, 2, 0,
     6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 7,
     0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 6, 1, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0,
     1, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2,
     0, 0, 7, 8, 0, 3, 9, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0,
     4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
     0, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 0};

     _Solve(arrBoard, 0, 0);

    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

its not the real code (just because the UI isnt important now).
so what I did here is to print the board every time it change any cell.
I saw one mistake while it tried to solve, when it reached to cell at row: 2 col: 6 (in index its [1][5]), it skip on the number 1 (which is the real answer), because it didnt try one, it cannot solve the rest of the sudoku.
i cant find out why it doesnt work.

Comment: This was asked yesterday by something else. A string reversing algorithm as well. Are all schools having their homework deadline this week?

Comment: OP says "I already asked for help here, but nobody answer".  Maybe the previous question was also his?

Comment: @user1895924, have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: are you forced to use recursion? There are much simpler approaches to this problem.

Comment: i am not learning programming in school, just a hobby

Comment: @CarlNorum THis program is actually for debuging, i print the new board after every step to see what values the board have..

Comment: That's not a debugger, that's logging.

Comment: @CarlNorum I tried to debug, same thing, it skip on the number 1(which is valid to put there, cus its the real answer), so i guess the problem is in IsValid Functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already accomplished the first step, identifying where and when the problem occurs. With the help of a debugger, you can step through `_Solve` when `iRow` is 1 and `iCol` is 5. Here's what I see, just looking at the first point when your problem occurs:

- `IsValid(arrBoard, iNewNum, iRow, iCol)` returns `FALSE`.
- Stepping into that method, `IsValidSquare(arrBoard, iNum, iCol, iRow)` is returning `FALSE`.
- Looking again at that line, it seems a bit odd that you've got `iCol` before `iRow`, when your pattern elsewhere is row-then-column. Comparing the call to the declaration/definition, it looks like you've mixed up the parameters at the call-site.

Fixing the order of the parameters for that call to `IsValidSquare` and re-running results in a solution.